How feasibly could the NES 2A03 chip use on-cartridge audio filters like the SID audio filters as a cheaper way to extend audio capabilities?
I am well aware of the SID's wide filtering capabilities. Ranging from a low, to high, to even a bandpass filter along with added resonance manipulation support, you could bring it insanely close to emulating various sound effects
This lends a huge flavor to SID audio that other contemporary chips simply could not do at the time. To top it off, compressed  4-bit sample playback  on the SID could just be passed through the filter, low-passed to clear out the noise
Now, the NES did have expansion audio chips. Well, at least the Famicom to be more precise. The MMC5, 5B, VRC6, and VRC7 chips for instance. These weren't used as much for their sound capabilities and were expensive to boot
On the other hand, a simple filtering chip would only consist of a small array of registers to hold values to control the filters, a capacitor for basic low-pass filtering, and an inductor for high-pass filtering, which compared to an entire VRC6 would have been freakishly cheap
Could the Famicom have used something like the above though? Instead of an entire expansion audio chip, a simple programmable audio filtering unit to either control one of the 2A03's two mixing units, or the entirety of the 2A03's outputted sound to allow for sounds that simply wouldn't have been possible otherwise?
Given how cheap such a solution could be, we could also toss in a couple extra audio effects such as compression to take its sound capabilities further. Question is, could this have been feasible for the system? A chip to manipulate existing sound instead of adding entire new sound channels? How much would it have costed, since the components themselves are cheap?

It is certainly possible but since it was not done it likely was not feasible.
Compared to the SID which can select which of the four audio channels are routed through the filter, the Famicom cartridge gets in one single audio wire which carries everything mixed together into one monophonic channel.
So while any further processing could happen in the cartridge, before the cartridge output is sent out from the AV connector, it can only process the single downmix it gets in.
Any filtering or effects would globally affect all audio output, so you cannot create such rich instruments than a SID can, because it has to use same filter for all 2A03 channels. Any low pass would make bass drum and bassline thinner, any high pass would remove hi-hat/noise.
SID can route only one channel through the filter to make a custom instrument, and keep other channels unprocessed.
On the other hand, on the Famicom it would likely need a cusrom sound processing filter IC with digital input control anyway. Adding registers/latches to store filter control info, adding some op-amp chips and mux ICs to allow different configurations would take too much space on the cartridge.
So yeah, it could have been great for modifying sound effects or choose a general "mood" for a song so different songs could have different "moods" or somethinh like a simulation of playing a same song differently when you are in different "rooms" of the game.
Reverb/echo would also have been too expensive at that time for such a cost-sensitive item.
Unfortunately, it might not have been such a killer feature or much more cheaper for a cartridge to only process the original audio than to add another sound chip for more and different sounds.

Assuming a very basic configuration of a low,hi and bandpass filter, won't the registers needed to store filter table information easily come under 80 bytes max? You store the kind of filter using 2 bits, store the cut off and resonance packed into 6 bits and store 80 of these 8-bit entries on a table. Certainly yes, reverb, compression would've been expensive, but basic filters would have been cheap right?

Or alternatively, to address the filter affecting all 5 channels, couldn't a simpler configuration be two or even one pulse channel with the filters in place? Basically a heavily stripped down MMC5 with filters?

I don't know whether the fabrication process for the 2A03 could produce a voltage follower with a constant-resistance output, but if not any good analog filtering would likely need to be external.  If one could have an analog output drive a fast constant-resistance voltage follower which then drove an RC circuit through a 4066 or similar device (using care to deal with charge leakage issues).  Time-multiplexing the output of the chip and allowing code to configure the time slot usage would allow adjustment of the low-pass filter behavior.
